# What is the best way to implement a Syntax Checker on my Interpreter for scripting code

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm writing a interpreter for one my custom scripting language.
this is the actual project on GitHub : [Link](https://github.com/EmaDev/Interpreter).
if someone wants to help me would be appreciated :)
however i need to implement a syntax checker for know if the syntax of code is correct from my parsed array of token.
What is the best way?

P.S. here i don't want use lex/yacc or flex and bison.

Comment: Since you have ruled out the other two most common parsers, I would say try boost::spirit or one of the other ones listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser_development_software)

Comment: I want to implement the parser from me. 
Not using the other library.

Comment: Well, "what is the best way to implement a parser" is too general and subjective a question for stackoverflow. Perhaps you can start trying to implement one and then ask a more specific question if you run into trouble.

Comment: The best way (least effort and pain) is to use a parser generator, which you don't want to do.  As a substitute, what you probably could do is hand-code a recursive descent parser. See this SO answer for details on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either implement your own parser, or use yacc/bison.

The dragon book is a good place to start (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design).

Also here is a sample C++ implementation of a top-down parser:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Comment: sorry but i have just implemented the tokenizer.
I need a logic for syntax checker, not for tokenizer with regex

Comment: The tokens are not enough to do syntax checking. Either implement your own parser as well, or use yacc/bison. Have you heard about the dragon book (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design)? Also here is a sample C++ implementation of a top-down parser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm already reading that book for a while.